# Unable to list files within specific folders with Google Drive api v3 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I've been working in updating the Google Drive v2 api to v3 in a file explorer app for iOS and I'm finding quite difficult to list the immediate children within a specific folder.

I've find a few posts with the following code but it hasn't worked.

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ in parents", parentIdQuery ? : @"root"];
```

I have tried using the `GTLDriveFile` property `identifier`in `parentIdQuery` as well as the `name`property.

When using the `name` property I receive the error

```
com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=404 "(File not found: .)"
```

And when I use the `identifier` property I get the root file list every time I try to enter to a directory (I can do this over and over again). Besides that I get the list of all the files every time but not only the root immediate children.

I'll appreciate any guidance you guys can give me on this.

Thanks!

PD:
I'm using the GTLCore project cloned from https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client

Google's Drive api documentation wasn't helpful.

Comment: You mentioned that the first code snippet you used is not working, how so? Have you tried following the code as in the [Querying for Files - Building Queries](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/queries#building_queries)?

Comment: The code snippet there is showing all the files al folder on the root, even if the ID in the query is from another folder.
I've tried following the code and I make and use my own queries as described in [Querying for Files - Building Queries](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/queries#building_queries) but I haven't figure it out what's wrong with this yet.

Comment: @sept Thanks! I figure it out. It was a problem with the query indeed, the `query.q` string I posted had the string `and mimeType = 'image/jpg' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` concatenated later in the code instead of `and (or mimeType = 'image/jpg' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')` and i haven't noticed. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with the query indeed, the query.q string I posted had the string `and mimeType = 'image/jpg' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` concatenated later in the code instead of `and (or mimeType = 'image/jpg' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')` and i haven't noticed.

Thanks [sept](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124253/sept) for your answer!

Comment: You should go on ahead and mark this as the correct answer. ;)